# Why is "violent" a synonym of "impetuous"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms

According to the Merriam-Webster dictionary, impetuous can be defined succinctly as "without thought or reason; controlled by emotion rather than thought". However, violent is listed as a synonym, when violent seems to be relegated purely to emotions of malice or rage. Impetuous seems to encompass all emotions (can actions done out of sadness/sorrow be considered impetuous?), whereas violent is limited to a few related emotions.

Why are these two synonyms if the domains in which they are correct differ?

Comment: A second meaning of *impetuous* is *[Having or marked by violent force](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=impetuous)*. Just because two words may share one meaning or usage does not mean they share all their other meanings and usages.

Comment: I'd put "impetuous" more in the realm of "rash". For some reason, it even strikes me as carrying some connotations of "impish", probably because of the "imp" part.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Impetuous implies sudden energy or speed.

"A bus with loosen breaks will go down a slope impetuously - without personal feeling"

Violent involves great strength (especially aggressively), or vehemence.

"His speech was violent - but the speaker didn't move"

The words are not synonymous.